# Un Boxing a class object - No Error?

Tags: c#, .net, unboxing

Probably I may be confused with boxing and unboxing.

Consider the following statement from MSDN:

> "Unboxing is an explicit conversion from the type object to a value
>   type or from an interface type to a value type that implements the
>   interface."

So, this implies that unboxing can only be applied to a value type parameter.

so, this is OK.

```
var concernedInteger = (int)myObject; //unboxing is ok.
```

Since class is a reference type, this should not work (because unboxing is only applicable to value type)

```
var concernedClassObject = (TestClass)testClassObject // unboxing is still ok.
```

My ReSharper does not show any error.

So, my question is "How can you unbox a reference type variable when MSDN says that only value types can be unboxed" ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't unboxing. It is `type casting`.

Unboxing is pulling the value from a reference out into a value type (assuming the cast will succeed). When you're moving reference types around like that.. it's just normal type casting.

Boxing and Unboxing are both types of `type casting` anyway. The reason they are given special names (boxing and unboxing) is because more goes on in a managed environment rather than just a couple of lookup tables being altered. This is why they are separated into the terms boxing and unboxing for value types.. but when it comes to reference types.. it's just type casting.

Comment: thanks for correcting me up. But again, does the same syntax follow to both unboxing and the type casting?

Comment: Updated my answer. Same syntax yes.. different things going on though.

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. That same syntax is used for very many things: reference conversions, boxing conversions, unboxing conversions, numerical conversions, user-defined conversions, method group conversions, and possibly others. They are all different!

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: Thanks a ton. Got clarified. One more doubt: whats the difference in type casting and using "as" operator ?

Answer (score 2):

what you are doing here is `TypeCasting` not boxing/unboxing. However the same casting syntax is used for both unboxing and explicit reference conversions

**Boxing And UnBoxing:**

`Boxing` and `unboxing` comes into play when you're casting a value type to and from a reference type, basically object

A simple `boxing` and `unboxing` example would be like

```
             int i=1;
             object o=i; /// This is boxing
             int j = (int)o; /// This is unboxing
```

**TypeCasting:**

Typecasting causes conversion.
A type cast performs an explicit conversion of an expression to a given type.

```
(type) expression
```

converts `expression` to an object of type `type`. Lets consider example

```
 long _longval = 1;
 int i = (int)_longval
```

Explicit casting actually tells the compiler that we know about possible information loss but still we need to perform cast. This is ok for inbuilt Numeric types but it might happen that in reference types it is not at all compatiable .for example

```
  string _mystring="abc";
  int i=(int)_mystring;
```

Such casting expressions will compile successfully but they will fail at run-time giving **InvalidCastException**  error.

**using As Keyword:**

example

```
  MyClass _MyObject = (MyClass ) obj;
  MyClass MyObject = obj as MyClass ;
```

When the cast fails at first line of code an exception is thrown whereas in the second line you get only **null** value.Also you can use **as** only with reference types so for value types you have to use normal casting method only.

Comment: You can clarify further. The conversion from `long` to `int` is a conversion between two value types, neither of which derives from the other, of course. In this case from a "wide" type (64-bit) to a "narrow" type (32-bit). This is very different from converting between a class type and its base class or interface. With your example from `string` to `int` you claim the expression compiles, but it does not. There is no conversion between `string` and `int` like that. But if you say `IComparable comp = "abc"; int i = (int)comp;` it would compile. That unboxing would fail at run-time.